# Tables are not created when initialize postgres docker with /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am trying to spin a postgres container from docker-compose, copying *.sql files to /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d in order to create the database and the schema.

The logs from the docker-compose run:

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: sourcing /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/02-schema.sql
db_1          | CREATE DATABASE
db_1          | GRANT
db_1          | SET
db_1          | CREATE TABLE
db_1          | CREATE INDEX
db_1          | CREATE TABLE
db_1          | CREATE TABLE
```

The database is created, but non of the tables is created. Below is my schema.sql file

```
CREATE DATABASE sample_db OWNER user1;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE sample_db TO user1;


CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.PROFILES(
    USER_ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

I used to do the same with my sql container, adding : USE sample_db, but I couldn't find the equivalent postgres command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you use the POSTGRES_DB environment variable in the docker file? If it isn't set it will use the POSTGRES_USER as database name

Check the environment variable in the documentation https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres

Comment: After setting this environment variable the tables defined in the init.sql script were all created. Works great, thanks.